# View inside ViewController not updating (IB Designables Error)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Recently I got this error:

> Failed to render and update auto layout status for YourViewController (GwR-7s-08s): The agent crashed

I've tried:

- Editor > Refresh all views
- Delete Derived Data
- Delete and Undo my view controller
- Restart My Pc

I'm really lost now.

This is what i found from console (~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports) IBDesignablesAgent-IOS.crash.

```
Process:               IBDesignablesAgent-iOS [8917]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/Xcode (Vers 10.1).app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/IBDesignablesAgent-iOS
Identifier:            IBDesignablesAgent-iOS
Version:               10.1 (14460.20)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [696]
Responsible:           IBDesignablesAgent-iOS [8917]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-04-15 18:02:05.468 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G103)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.1 (17P1081)
Anonymous UUID:        CBF175F5-90A8-CA46-157A-EAC22B0E9C53


Time Awake Since Boot: 7000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [8917]

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 681.15 - Device: iPhone 8 (B66229B4-2385-44FD-B679-B71B2306DF10) - Runtime: iOS 12.1 (16B91) - DeviceType: iPhone 8
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000226d276f1 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 113
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000226b5d053 _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 19
2   com.MiCaresvc.MyMed             0x0000000225e03dac UsefulLinksTableViewCell.layoutSubviews() + 268
3   com.MiCaresvc.MyMed             0x0000000225e041f4 @objc UsefulLinksTableViewCell.layoutSubviews() + 36
4   com.apple.UIKitCore             0x000000011d38d795 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1441
5   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x000000010e885b19 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 175
6   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x000000010e88a9d3 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 395
7   com.apple.UIKitCore             0x000000011d378077 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1429
8   com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x000000010d33d267 -[UITableViewCell(IBCocoaTouchToolIntegration) awakeAfterMarshallerDidEstablishAttributesWithContext:] + 58
9   com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x000000010d332248 -[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage initWithRequest:globalMarshallingContext:] + 3391
10  com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x000000010d330d91 +[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage objectPackageFromRequest:] + 67
11  com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x000000010d333f1e +[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 106
12  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e54241c -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] + 109
13  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e5e2e4f -[IBObjectBasedMarshallingRequest initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 135
14  com.apple.dt.IBAutolayoutFoundation 0x000000010e4b2f63 -[IBFullSceneUpdateRequest initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 65
15  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e538f05 +[NSObject(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 65
16  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e54241c -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] + 109
17  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e54281d -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObjectReferenceIfPossible] + 74
18  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e539486 -[NSArray(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 180
19  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e538f05 +[NSObject(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 65
20  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e54241c -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] + 109
21  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e62e745 -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:] + 424
22  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e62e152 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke + 143
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001167f954b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000116806036 _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 109
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001167f954b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000116805380 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1290
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001105183e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000110512a76 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000110511e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
30  com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010eaea322 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
31  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e5e9c36 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 447
32  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e5e9ef2 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 119
33  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010e5ead9a +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1211
34  IBDesignablesAgent-iOS          0x000000010d253957 main + 34
35  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000116869575 start + 1
```

Comment: That generally happens when you have an error in your custom class. Does it work properly at run-time? Do you get any error / warning messages? Do you have objects that need to be initialized but aren't (as shown in the error message you posted: *"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"*)?    Have you implemented `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`?

Comment: I'm able to run the app with no issue.

Just found out what happen. I'm able to solve this when i removed this code in my cell.

override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
    
            curveUIVIEW.layer.cornerRadius = curveUIVIEW.layer.frame.height / 2
    
    //        curveUIVIEW.layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
            self.curveUIVIEW.layer.masksToBounds = true
            self.curveUIVIEW.clipsToBounds = true
    
    
        }

Comment: OK - so *something* in your code is causing the IB crash. If you edit your question and post the full code for your `@IBDedsignable` view, we can try to help you find the actual problem.